# Using the residual standard deviation of a weighted standard regression for effect size computation

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, effect-size, weighted-regression

I'm facing a trivial problem but I want to be sure that the approach is appropriate. I have a situation in which *n* subjects perform a task with *k* trials for each subject. *k* is not a fixed number and so I can have a subject with a different number of trials (i.e. precision).

If I compute the standard error of the mean of each subject and use this as a **weight** n a weighted linear regression, using $\frac{1}{weight}$ I should correctly consider the precision of each subject (instead of simply performing a subject-level mean and the linear regression).

My question is, if I compute an effect size, like the `cohen's d`, as $\frac{\beta}{sd_{error}}$ so the estimated regression coefficients divided by the residual standard error. The residual standard error is usually higher in weighted regression, and so effect size are usually lower. My question is whether the residual standard error is **genuinely** estimated as higher or if is due to the weighted regression itself and so is not directly interpretable.